# Jquery getting value from php to validate datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to get an array from a php( invalid dates) and mark them in red in the date picker.. Below code does not populate the unavilableDates. What am i doing wrong.. It displays all dates.. Thanks for any help.

```
   $(document).on("focus", "#cust_slot1date", function () {
   var unavailableDates = [];

   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ddateavbl.php",
        success: function (data) {
            unavailableDates = data;
        }
      });

    $("#cust_slot1date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'D dd-M-yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
   });

   function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +     date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ''];
    } else {
        return [false, '', 'Unavailable'];
    }
   }

   });
```

Comment: Have you checked for logs/errors in the developer tools? Seems like you may have a scope issue there. I would try `console.log(unavailableDates);` inside your ajax success, and also in your `unavailable` function to verify the array is available for use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    if($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('D dd-M-yy', date ), unavilableDates) > -1)
    {
        return [false,"","Unavailable"];
    }
    else
    {
        return [true,'',""];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works.. but now i am into different issue. The unavailable date are highlighted only on the second time when i focus.

Answer (score -1):

This is the working code, if anyone is looking for. This solves the first focus not working and works from second time focus.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var unavailableDates = [];

     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ddateavbl.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            unavailableDates = data;
        }
      });

    $(document).on("focus", "#cust_slot1date", function () {

    $("#cust_slot1date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'D dd-M-yy',
       beforeShowDay: function(date) {
       if($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date ), unavailableDates) > -1)
           {
             return [false,"","Unavailable"];
           }
            else
          {
             return [true,'',""];
           }
        }
       });

});
});
```

Comment: Edit your original post